# Merging pandas dataframes to produce a dataframe with lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames with the same column names and the same indices. Each entry
in the data frames is an int or a float. I would like to combine the data frames into
a single data frame. I would like each entry of this data frame to be a list containing the individual elements from the separate data frames.

As an example, df1 and df2 are the original data frames:

```
         A  B
df1 = 0  0  1

         A  B
df2 = 0  2  3
```

I would like to produce the following dataframe:

```
            A       B
df3 = 0  [0, 2]  [1, 3]
```

I tried the following:

```
merger = lambda s1, s2: s1.append(s2)
df1.combine(df2, merger)
```

This gives me the error:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

I can think of a few ways to do it with loops but I'd like to avoid that if possible. It seems like this is something that should be built into pandas.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
out = pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```